# Syntax error during associative array expansion in Bash 4.2

Tags: bash, syntax-error, associative-array

all

I got two 2D-array files to read with bash

these two files contain different rows x columns such as:

file1.txt (nx6)

```
DIFFUSION X 0.054 0.072 Y E2
DEEP_N_WELL X 1.8 2.25 N D
PW_CORE X 0.306 0.306 Y U1
PW_IO X 0.306 0.306 Y T1
NW_CORE X 0.306 0.306 Y U1
NW_IO X 0.306 0.306 Y T1
TG X 0.306 0.306 N S1
N+_POLY_IMP X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
POLY1 X 0.036 0.09 Y F2
LV_NLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
LV_PLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
LPL_NLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
LPL_PLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
CELL_NLDD X 0.216 0.216 N U1
CELL_PLDD X 0.216 0.216 N U1
HV_NLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
HV_PLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
N+ X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
P+ X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
SMT X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
PESD X 0.486 0.486 N A
SAB X 0.324 0.324 N S1
CONTACT X 0.054 0.072/0.090 Y F1
METAL1 1x 0.063 0.063 Y E2
MVIA1 1x 0.063 0.063/0.081 Y E1
METAL2 1x 0.063 0.063 Y E2
MVIA2 1x 0.063 0.063/0.081 Y E1
METAL3 1x 0.063 0.063 Y E2
MVIA3 1x 0.063 0.063/0.081 Y E1
METAL4 1x 0.063 0.063 Y E2
MVIA4 1x 0.063 0.063/0.081 Y E1
METAL5 1x 0.063 0.063 Y E2
MVIA5 1x 0.063 0.063/0.081 Y E1
METAL6 1x 0.063 0.063 Y E2
MVIA6 6x 0.31 0.320/0.320 N S1
METAL7 6x 0.32 0.4 N S1
TMV_RDL X 1.8 1.8 N B
AL_RDL X 1.8 1.8 N B
PASV_RDL X 5.4 5.4 N B
N_WELL X 0.306 0.306 NULL U1
HP_CELL_NLDD X 0.216 0.216 N U1
HP_CELL_PLDD X 0.216 0.216 N U1
LVH_NLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
LVH_PLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
LVUL_NLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
LVUL_PLDD X 0.162 0.162 Y T1
CG X 0.306 0.306 N S1
AW X 1.5 1.5 N B
```

file2.txt (mx3)

```
DIFFUSION 0.054 0.072 
POLY1 0.036 0.090 
SMT 0.162 0.162 
VTNH 0.162 0.162 
VTPH 0.162 0.162 
N+_POLY_IMP 0.162 0.162 
P+_POLY_IMP 0.162 0.162 
LV_NLDD 0.162 0.162 
LV_PLDD 0.162 0.162 
HV_NLDD 0.162 0.162 
HV_PLDD 0.162 0.162 
LVL_NLDD 0.162 0.162 
LVL_PLDD 0.162 0.162 
LVH_NLDD 0.162 0.162 
LVH_PLDD 0.162 0.162 
LPL_NLDD 0.162 0.162 
LPL_PLDD 0.162 0.162 
HVL_NLDD 0.162 0.162 
N+ 0.162 0.162 
P+ 0.162 0.162 
SG 0.162 0.162 
VTP_WLDR 0.162 0.162 
VTN_WLDR 0.162 0.162 
HS_CELL_PLDD 0.216 0.216 
HS_CELL_NLDD 0.216 0.216 
NW_CORE 0.306 0.306 
PW_CORE 0.306 0.306 
PW_IO 0.306 0.306 
NW_IO 0.306 0.306 
DT 0.090 0.118 
CONTACT 0.054 0.072/0.091 
METAL1 0.063 0.063 
MVIA1 0.063 0.063/0.081 
METAL2 0.063 0.063 
MVIA2 0.063 0.063/0.081 
METAL3 0.063 0.063 
MVIA3 0.063 0.063/0.081 
METAL4 0.063 0.063 
MVIA4 0.063 0.063/0.081 
METAL5 0.063 0.063 
MVIA5 0.063 0.063/0.081
METAL6 0.063 0.063 
MVIA6 0.063 0.063/0.081 
METAL7 0.063 0.063 
MVIA7 0.126 0.126 
METAL8 0.126 0.126 
MVIA8 0.126 0.126 
METAL9 0.126 0.126
```

what I wanna do is to extract the elements inside both files then do some comparisons as following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPp3a.png

"DESC1==DESC2" or "DESC1!=DESC2" in green label is a obstructer for me
I really wanna do is to take one element in $DESC1 and compare with whole elements in ${DESC2[@]}, if it does/dosen't find a element in ${DESC2[@]} then feedback true/false

Here is my work:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

##===================================================================##
##===================================================================##
##========== read information from file1.txt and file2.txt ==========##
##===================================================================##
##===================================================================##

idx1=0

while read -a file1array$idx1; do
    let idx1++
done < file1.txt

idx2=0

while read -a file2array$idx2; do
    let idx2++
done < file2.txt

##===================================================================##
##===================================================================##
##================ start to compare these two files =================##
##===================================================================##
##===================================================================##

for ((i=0; i<idx1; i++)); do
   for ((j=0; j<idx2; j++)); do

    DESC1="file1array$i[0]"
    DM1="file1array$i[1]"
    W1="file1array$i[2]"
    S1="file1array$i[3]"
    CRITICAL1="file1array$i[4]"
    GRADE1="file1array$i[5]"

    DESC2="file2array$j[0]"
    W2="file2array$j[1]"
    S2="file2array$j[2]"


    if [[ "${!GRADE1}" == [E-GT-Z][1-9] && "${!DESC1}" == "${!DESC2}" ]]; then 

         W1_Judge=`expr "scale=3; ${!W1} - ${!W2}" | bc`
         S1_Judge=`expr "scale=3; ${!S1} - ${!S2}" | bc`

         [ $W1_Judge != 0 -o $S1_Judge != 0 ] && declare -A jgWS=( ["${!DESC1}"]="WSNG" )

    elif [[ "${!GRADE1}" == [E-GT-Z][1-9] && "${!DESC1}" != "${!DESC2}" ]]; then 

         [ "${!CRITICAL1}" != "NULL" ] && declare -A jgLOSS=( ["${!DESC1}"]="LOSSNG" )

    elif [[ "${!GRADE1}" != [E-GT-Z][1-9] && "${!DESC1}" == "${!DESC2}" ]]; then 

         [[ "$DM1" == [1-2]x || "$DM1" == "X" ]] && declare -A jgEXTRA=( ["${!DESC1}"]="EXTRANG" )

    else

         declare -A jgBYPASS=( ["${!DESC1}"]="OK" )

    fi

  done

  if [ "${jgWS[${!DESC1}]}" == "WSNG" ]; then

      echo "${!DESC1} : W or S NG"

  elif [ "${jgLOSS[${!DESC1}]}" == "LOSSNG" ]; then

      echo "${!DESC1} : LOSS NG"

  elif [ "${jgEXTRA[${!DESC1}]}" == "EXTRANG" ]; then

      echo "${!DESC1} : EXTRA NG"

  else

      echo "${!DESC1} : OK"

  fi

done
```

1. How can I solve the part of green label or is there any easier way to achieve the goal? I feel that I'm very close but turns out I'm just stuck with for-loop and test
2. The error message is "N+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")"
   Actually I can simply define "declare -A jgEXTRA=( ["N+"]="EXTRANG" )" and "echo {jgEXTRA[N+]}"
   so I don't know what's going on? Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: There's a lot of indirection here, so it's a little hard to tell what you are trying to do. However, you can skip the obfuscated `sed` step by using `if [[ "${!GRADE1}" = [E-GT-Z][1-9] && ... ]]; then` (that is, use pattern matching instead of replacing the target pattern with a sentinel string and checking for that).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Check out the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for tips on posting, such as why and how to create small, self-contained examples of problematic code.

Comment: I just clarify my question and modify some script with sentinel string based on chepner's suggestion, thanks for your opinions!

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question:**

The complexity of your script is high. It would be an issue if file1 and file2 are big. You should sort them to reduce the complexity (from N^2 to log N).

Do you consider to use ['comm' command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html)? I think this does a big part of the job and could let you simplify your script a lot

**For the second question:**

It seems you do not initialize jgWS in some condition. When it happens, ${jgWS[a]} return empty string, but ${jgWS[a+]} prints your error message. I am not sure to understand why, but it is what I observed.

**Other remarks**

You read loops, at the begining, will miss the last lines of file1 and file2 if they are not terminated by a Linux Line Feed (because read returns false when it doesn't finish on LF).